# PayPal HTML form Basics with unencrypted values

Tags: html, paypal

is it still possible to use the PayPal HTML form Basics with unencrypted values in hidden fields? I know that people can change easily the value in the form, but can I use it or there is a problem with PayPal? Can PayPal block or limit my account if in my site I use this kind of form to pass the payment value? Thanks

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller@site.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="hat">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="15.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="John">
  <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Doe">
  <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="9 Elm Street">
  <input type="hidden" name="address2" value="Apt 5">
  <input type="hidden" name="city" value="Berwyn">
  <input type="hidden" name="state" value="PA">
  <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="19312">
  <input type="hidden" name="night_phone_a" value="610">
  <input type="hidden" name="night_phone_b" value="555">
  <input type="hidden" name="night_phone_c" value="1234">
  <input type="hidden" name="email" value="jdoe@test.com">
  <input type="image" name="submit"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
    alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
</form>
```

Comment: I haven't used the PayPal API, but as a consumer I will say that if I ever saw this in HTML on a site I was about to put my payment information into, I would *definitely* not go through with my transaction. It's a legitimate question, but please for the love of all that is good do *not* do this in production.

Comment: Ok for security, I know that is a bad solution. I want to know if for PayPal is a problem a form like this and if they can close or limit my account.

Answer (score 0):

For backwards compatibility with old websites, legacy HTML forms like this will still work. They redirect to the PayPal site, and the PayPal site securely collects the payment information.

However, there is absolutely no reason to use an HTML form. The current [HTML/JS Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client) supports all the same features of the above and more. It presents a modern, in-context experience and does not redirect away from your site.